# Segfault when calling gtk_drawing_area_new

Tags: gtk3

I have just a simple program

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main() {
    GtkWidget * drawingarea = gtk_drawing_area_new(); // <-- Segfault
    return 0;
}
```

which just creates a drawing area. But it segfaults. Why? I'm using ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `gtk_init` before the call to `gtk_drawing_area_new` solves this problem.